# An urn contains 5 red balls, 6 green balls, and 7 white balls. Three balls are drawn without replacement.

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability that the third ball is green given that the first two balls were white?

Since there's no replacement, once the white balls are taken out you only have 16 balls to choose from. After this I'm stumped on where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are initially 18 balls, and as you mentioned, once you have chosen and removed the first two (white) balls, you are left with 16 balls.

Of those 16 balls, 6 are green. So the probability of picking a green ball is 6/16.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out lol. What about if you have 78 red marbles, 28 blue and the rest are green and the probability of picking a green one is 1/3, what would the probability of picking a red one be?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: If you have 78 red marbles, 24 blue marbles, and the rest of the bag are green marbles and the probability of picking a green marble is 1/3, what is the probability of picking a red marble?

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: The total number of marbles isn't given, though. It just says the rest of the bag is made up of green marbles after the first 102, and that 1/3 is the probability of getting a green marble from the bag....

Comment: Sorry- A bag contains a number of marbles, 78 of which are red, 24 of which are blue, and the rest are green. If the probability of selecting a green marble is 1/3, what is the probability of selecting a red marble?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Let's say X is the number of green marbles. So we have a total of 102+X marbles. We know the probability of selecting a green marble is X/(102+X)=1/3. You can now solve for X. Once you do, you can get the probability of selecting a red marble by the same formula: 24/(102+X).

Comment: But how do I solve for X ? I'm sorry, I'm terrible at probability and my teacher doesn't help much....

Comment: NEVERMIND! I GOT IT! 0.51!!

Comment: Or 51/100 in reduced fraction form lol

Comment: Just kidding, 26/51 reduced fraction